# Why can't pgrep find a process?

Tags: process, grep, ps

Consider:

```
$ ps -ef | grep myprocess
root    7204     1 99 23:37 ?        00:02:36 ./myprocess
drew    7439  7266  0 23:38 pts/0    00:00:00 grep myprocess
$ pgrep myprocess
```

The process in question is a service controlled by upstart.

Why can't `pgrep` see this process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got this to work by including the `-f` option:

```
-f, --full
    The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is
    set, the full command line is used.
```

With which:

```
$ pgrep -f myprocess
1234
```

Comment: so strange this is the default. it should search for either first. thanks for figuring this out!